# How to use three different tkinter buttons with one command

Tags: button, tkinter, lambda, command, python-3.6

Please house help. When using tkinter, I find it difficult to call a defined function in a button when the def is below the button. I use python 3.6.9. Example

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk
button = tkinter.Button(window, text="hello",command=newpage()).grid(column=0, row=0)
def newpage():
    new = tkinter.toplevel()
```

The button does not work except I use lambda and also the lambda does not work if I define something new under the button. The new definition blocks the lambda from seeing the other def. 
NB: I use the lambda like this `lambda:newpage()`
NB: I use python 3.6.9
Also please how can I make many tkinter buttons to use the same command (as in def)

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432 . Can you expand your question to show how your question is different?

Comment: @ Bryan please don't close the question. Stackflow has been my resort for most challenges I have and i've searched over and over but couldn't find the solution from any previous questions. Please help me solve this problem. I want to have two buttons using the same def command but it's not working on my tkinter. Lambda is not working either. Please help me in anyway you can.

Comment: Please show that you've tried the advice from that other question. As that other question shows, `command` needs to be given as `newpage`, not `newpage()`.

Comment: Okay. Really appreciate. Checking the link also now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, you're saying you asked me not to close _before_ you followed that link? Why did you not check out the link first?

Comment: I'm checking it when you made your comment

Comment: If you used lambda like `command=lambda: newpage()`, `newpage()` can be defined after the button creation line.

Answer (score 1):

The `newpage` function should really be defined before being used, just as a good programming practice if for no other reason.

The variable `window` is being set to `tkinter.Tk` instead of the object returned by `tkinter.Tk()`.

The button is calling the function immediately because command expects a function to run, and thinks you want it to run something returned by newpage, instead remove the `()` `command=newpage`.

Toplevel is capitalized, `tkinter.Toplevel()`.

A function can be used by any button, just assign the command to use the function:

```
import tkinter

def newpage():
    new = tkinter.Toplevel()

window = tkinter.Tk()
button1 = tkinter.Button(window,
                         text="hello1",
                         command=newpage).grid(column=0, row=0)
button2 = tkinter.Button(window,
                         text="hello2",
                         command=newpage).grid(column=0, row=1)
button3 = tkinter.Button(window,
                         text="hello3",
                         command=newpage).grid(column=0, row=2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted your statement. I was thinking you said you should create the toplevel before it is used. I'll remove my comment. You are correct that a function must be defined before its used.